# What level is a typical Belkzen orc?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion, orc

I am working on a campaign where my party will have a big adventure in Belkzen. What level is the average orc in Belkzen? I have read the orc guide but I still do not know what level an ordinary orc would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No *average* level was officially given

The [Hold of Belkzen](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Hold_of_Belkzen) is a large piece of land, not a dungeon or city, and you can find creatures of all challenge ratings there, so the developers won't give you premade npc/monster sheets because you can find all sort of creatures there, from humans and halflings (like some [shoanti](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Shoanti#Shundar-Quah_.28The_Spire_Clan.29)) to dragons and liches (and i am [dead serious](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Scarwall)). Even their capital city, [Urgir](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Urgir), has about 1.150 humans, 290 elves, 275 half-elves and 881 *others*, and that is more human-ish population than a [small town](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/settlements/).

Which means that, even though the place has a *lot* of orcs, they are not the sole inhabitants there, and considering the size of the place, you can find orc farmers of 1/2 CR and orc chieftains of CR 15+. There is even a [CR 16 lizard-like thing with a snake for tail](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Juggerloathe) roaming the *Conquered Lands* (southern area).

I suggest you get a copy of the [Belzen, Hold of the Orc Hordes](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9aue/discuss&page=6?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Belkzen-Hold-of-the-Orc-Hordes) campaign setting book, you will get a ton of adventure ideas there with it, plus locations, geography, villages and cities, important NPCs, etc.

The [Monster Codex](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9926?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Monster-Codex) is also pretty useful as it contains orc sheets with a variet sort of class levels to be used by GM, some of which can be found on the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsterCodex/orcs.html).